# How to use the Python connectors to mySQL to REPLACE INTO multiple rows

Tags: python, mysql

The overarching question here is how to get a multirow REPLACE INTO statement that works with None in the format "REPLACE INTO ... VALUES (...), (...).

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html we have this example where executemany(stmt, params) for INSERT statements ONLY forms the multiple row format:

```
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) VALUES ('Jane', '2005-02-12'), ('Joe', '2006-05-23'), ('John', '2010-10-03')
```

But for all other statement types, it creates one query per tuple in params.  For performance reasons, we want to bundle a REPLACE INTO in this multirow format.

The field list looks like this:

child_item_count, name, type_default, parent_id, version, agent_id, folder_id

and some of them are permitted to be NULL.

Originally, I tried to just build a statement string with all of the tuples comma added to the operational part of the query. Given list_of_tuples looks like [(None,'a string',8,'UUID',190L,'UUID','UUID'),...]:

```py
insert_query = "REPLACE INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES {} " % (table, column_names)
values = ', '.join(map(str, list_of_tuples))
sql = insert_query.format(values)
db_cursor.execute(sql)
```

but I got:

Error writing to database: OperationalError(1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")

I've also tried just shipping the list to execute() as in db_cursor.execute(insert_query, list_of_tuples) and that doesn't work, either. That results in "TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)"

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Your code contains the possibility of SQL Injection.**

The issue is pretty simple:
The `map(a, b)` function will run the `a(el)` for each element in b.

In your case, it will get every tuple on the list and convert it to a string, therefore a given tuple `(None, 4, 'b')` will turn into `(None, 4, 'b')` - and `None` is not a valid keyword on MySQL.

The best way to fix this is to rely on the execute command to convert the values correctly, making it **sql injection free**:

```
import itertools

columns_count = 10 # Change this value according to your columns count
column_values = '(' + ', '.join(['%s'] * columns_count) + ')'
values = ', '.join([column_values]*len(list_of_tuples))
# (...)
insert_query = insert_query.format(values)
db_cursor.execute(insert_query, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_tuples)))
```

---

Although there is the second option (Bellow), it would make your code vulnerable to SQL Injection. So **don't use it**.

Simply to convert the values directly, making the necessary adjustments (In this specific scenario, it is just changing None to NULL):

```
values = ', '.join('('+', '.join(map(lambda e: str(e) if e else "NULL", t))+')' for t in list_of_tuples)
```

Comment: So, we aren't concerned about SQL injection in this environment because the code is copying data from one internal database to another internal database (i.e., from production to staging).

Which isn't to say that your suggestion isn't useful otherwise, just that there are times when injection isn't the showstopper it normally is.

I will test out your examples tomorrow, many thanks.